# Como llamar una función de fecha en jsp

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-8.2

espero puedan ayudarme con esto. Tengo un box de tipo fecha, el cual abre y muestra el calendario o tambien se puede ingresar la fecha. El detalle es que necesito me muestre la fecha actual por defecto, tengo una funcion que hace eso, pero no se donde colocarla o como llamarla.
Por favor su ayuda.

```html
<td> Fecha</td>
<td><label>
       <input name="txtfec_clave" type="text" id="txtfec_clave" 
       value="" 
       onkeypress="enfocarControl('txtfec_baja', event); hideCalendarControl(); 
       return acceptNumFecha(event);" 
       class="textos" onFocus="focotext(this); showCalendarControl(this);" 
       onBlur="nofocotext(this);" 
       maxlength="10" size="15" />
    </label> (dd/mm/aaaa) </td>
```

Y me muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿usas JSTL o es en modo básico?

Comment: Es un método básico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la fecha no tiene que venir del servidor puedes intentar llenarlo usando JavaScript desde el lado cliente, simplemente buscas por Id tu input y allí le insertas el valor de el día de hoy en el formato que lo necesites.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
}
var todayformatted = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
document.getElementById('txtfec_clave').value = todayformatted;
```

```html
<td> Fecha</td>
<td><label>
       <input name="txtfec_clave" type="text" id="txtfec_clave" 
       value="new Date()" 
       onkeypress="enfocarControl('txtfec_baja', event); hideCalendarControl(); 
       return acceptNumFecha(event);" 
       class="textos" onFocus="focotext(this); showCalendarControl(this);" 
       onBlur="nofocotext(this);" 
       maxlength="10" size="15" />
    </label> (dd/mm/aaaa) </td>
```

Comment: Gracias, quedo bien. Saludos.